# Will Map[] be nullable or non-nullable?

Tags: dart

I am playing around with the experimental non-nullable feature. I am really excited since this is my #1 missing feature in Dart!

However, my code fails calling `[]` on Maps because the return type is non-nullable and all my subsequent null checks are flagged as “not needed”.

Will `V operator [](Object key);` be turned into `V? operator [](Object key);` once nnbd is released?

Is there a way to make this work already now? For example, is there already an (experimental) nnnd version of the SDK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Most likely* the `[]` operator on `Map` will get the type `V? operator[](Object key)`.
This allows existing map implementations to keep working.

The alternative is to change the implementation of all existing maps to throw whenever there is no entry for a key, or perhaps only when the value-type is non-nullable. 
That would require a lot of code to be rewritten, code that reasonably assumed that checking for a `null` return value is a correct use of the `[]` operator.

Comment: Any idea when an SDK will be available?